# Parse NSURL scheme iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, url-scheme

I have the following URL scheme for my app:

```
MyApp://add/web=something.com
```

I'd need to check whether `add` is actually add or something else, how can I parse that part from the NSURL?

Also, how can I parse `web=something.com` from the NSURL?

Thanks!

Comment: `NSURLComponents`.

Comment: Is `web=something.com` a query parameter?